# Subclass unable to access parent class' variable

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, virtual-functions

I'm making a program whereby I have a `Square` class which is a subclass of `Shape` class

But my program crashes when the subclass tries to access variable from parent class.

Here is my code:

```
class Shape2D
{
public:
    string shape;
    void setShape(string newShape);
    string getShape();

    string specialType;
    void setSpecialType(string newSpecialType);

    vector <int> shapeXCoordi;
    void setshapeXCoordi(int newshapeXCoordi);

    vector <int> shapeYCoordi;
    void setshapeYCoordi(int newshapeYCoordi);
    void toString();

    virtual int computeArea()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    void displayArea();
};
```

For testing purpose, I only make this `computeArea()` return the x-coordinate.

```
class Square : public Shape2D
{
public:
    int computeArea()
    {
        return shapeXCoordi[0];
    }
};

int main()
{
    if (aShape2D[0].getShape() == "Square")
    {
        Shape2D *pShape2D;
        pShape2D = &aSquare;

        cout << "Area: " << pShape2D -> computeArea()  << endl;
    } 
}
```

I did a couple of test, if I were to change `return shapeXCoordi[0];` to `return 123;`, it works fine.

I also tried `return shape;` but it will not display anything, although this time, it doesn't crash.

So I'm guessing there is something wrong when `SquareClass` is trying to access `shapeXCoordi[0]` from `ShapeClass`

Can anyone enlighten me on this situation?

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with the inheritance. How are you initializing `aShape2D` and how are you initializing `shapeXCoordi`?

Comment: i have a 'Shape2D aShape2D[100]' in my main whereby i could store up to 100 shapes. As for shapeXCoordi, its a vector whereby it stores the x-coordinate of every vertices of a shape, in this case, a square

Comment: Is it due to the fact that i have an array of Shape2D, thus when i call for shapeXCoordi[0] it doesnt know which shape's shapeXCoordi[0] to look into?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the shapeXCoordi in your constructor by calling setshapeXCoordi first. Since you are accessing shapeXCoordi, an uninitialized vector, there are no elements in it. Hence when you access it using [0] it returns an error.

You can add a sanity check to computeArea() to ensure there is an element in shapeXCoordi before you access it:

```
int computeArea()
{
    assert(shapeXCoordi.size() != 0);
    return shapeXCoordi[0];
}
```

Also, I recommend using .at(0) instead of [0], this way you get actual error handling instead of a crash.